# Python: Remove string pattern in string

Tags: python, regex

I get stuck when I was processing some strings. I got a string looked like `"absed\".'\"xgtwa@aiuyr.com"`, but I run out idea how to change the strange pattern `\".'\"` to `.`.

I used code like this:

```
 s = re.sub(r'\".'\"', '.', s)
```

but it returned `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`.

The output string should be `"absed.xgtwa@aiuyr.com"`. The input is simply finding the email address. For example, for a line (`x`) in a file, the line is `To: absed.xgtwa@aiuyr.com`, my "input" is just `x.split(":")[1]`. BTW, in other files, it worked perfectly. But sometimes it occurred such problem.

Any help will be thankful!

Comment: Can you put up your input and expected output more clearly

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan just updated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using single quotation marks `'` and `s` contains a single quotation mark which isn't an escape character `\'`.

Change `s = re.sub(r'\".'\"', '.', s)` to `s = re.sub(r"\".'\"", ".", s)`.

```
import re

s = "absed\".'\"xgtwa@aiuyr.com"
print("Pre-regex:\ts = %s" % s)

s = re.sub(r"\".'\"", ".", s)
print("Post-regex:\ts = %s" % s)
```

So that the output becomes:

```
Pre-regex:      s = absed".'"xgtwa@aiuyr.com
Post-regex:     s = absed.xgtwa@aiuyr.com
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a one liner but it gets the job done, I believe.

```
s="absed\".'\"xgtwa@aiuyr.com"
s=s.replace('\"','')
s=s.replace("'",'')
s=s.replace('\"','')
print(s)
```

results in

```
absed.xgtwa@aiuyr.com
```